# Generating array from multiple folder paths

Tags: powershell

Alright, I am confusing my self on how to get this to work. I have several folder locations that have multiple sub-folders. These sub-folders are all named after hosts on our network. So I am working on a script to validate the contents of the folders for auditing purposes. I can not seem to generate a usable list that has the system name derived from the folder name and the full path name. I.G.

```
Name        Path
----        ----
system1     \\path\rootfolder1\system1
system2     \\path\rootfolder1\system2
system3     \\path\rootfolder2\system3
```

I get the root folders from a CSV file as the folders are not all in one location and I do not need to use every folder time I run the report.

```
#Path to folder repository. Folder names must be the systems host name. 
$list_paths = (Import-Csv 'C:\CVS\path\Paths.csv').path

#list arrays
$list = @()
$list2= @()

#Counters
$p_count = 0
$l_count = 0


#Generates array (list) of folder paths
Foreach ($p1 in $list_paths){
$l_count ++
$listx1 = Get-ChildItem $p1 | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | Foreach-object {$_.FullName}
$list += $listx1
}

#Generates array (list) of system names from folder
ForEach ($p2 in $list){
$p_count ++
Write-Host $p2
$listx2 = split-path -path $p2 -leaf
$list2 += $listx2
}


$Output = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        "Name" = $list
        "Path" = $list2
        }

Write-Host ($Output | Format-table | Out-String)

Write-Host Number of root folders
Write-Host $l_count
Write-Host Number of host folders
Write-Host $p_count'
```

So when I run the script `$output` produces this instead of the format I want above.

```
Name
----
{\\path\rootfolder1\system1, \\path\rootfolder2\system2, \\path\root...}
```

I know I am doing something wrong but I can seem to figure out what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only create one object with every name and every path as the property-values, not one "Name + Path"-object per system-folder like your first example. Also, you're mixing your lists, so the paths ended up in the `Name`-property.

Try moving the `New-Object` job inside a foreach-loop that processes the system-folders. I'd also recommend readable variable-names.

```
#Path to folder repository. Folder names must be the systems host name. 
$rootpaths = (Import-Csv 'C:\CVS\path\Paths.csv').path

#Systems found
$systems = @()

#Find system-folders inside each root
Foreach ($root in $rootpaths){
    Get-ChildItem $root | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } | Foreach-object {
        #Foreach system-folder, generate a result object
        $systems += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            #No need to split the path. The object already contains the leaf-name in the Name-property
            "Name" = $_.Name
            "Path" = $_.FullName
        }
    }
}

#No need for write-host if you're writing everything as strings anyways
$systems | Format-table | Out-String

"Number of root folders: $($rootpaths.Count)"
"Number of host folders $($systems.Count)"
```

As mentioned by @TheMadTechnician, if use the pipeline for what it's worth, this can actually be shortened down to:

```
#Path to folder repository. Folder names must be the systems host name. 
$rootpaths = (Import-Csv 'C:\CVS\path\Paths.csv').path

#Find system-folders inside each root
$systems = Get-ChildItem -Path $rootpaths | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } | Select-Object Name, FullName
#Or this if you have Powershell 3.0+
#$systems = Get-ChildItem -Path $rootpaths -Directory | Select-Object Name, FullName

#No need for write-host if you're writing everything as strings anyways
$systems | Format-table | Out-String

"Number of root folders: $($rootpaths.Count)"
"Number of host folders $($systems.Count)"
```

Comment: Even better, don't rebuild `$systems` each time, just output the objects and capture all loop output. Also, `Get-ChildItem` takes an array of strings, so this turns into `$systems = GCI $rootpaths -directory | Select Name,@{l='Path';e={$_.FullName}}`

Comment: I agree and prefer your solution. I aimed for the most readable code this time due to the level of the code in the question. :-)